# Lenovo Vibe P1 randomly reboots after upgrading to Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, reboot, lenovo-vibe-p1

I use Lenovo Vibe P1 Series Phone. I got it upgraded to Marshmallow and ever since then it reboots each time I locks the screen. It's working perfectly when I'm using it. It was working perfectly when I had Lollipop.

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: There's someone who got the same issue, and he mentioned about [restricting any app under 'background app management'](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/P-Series-Smartphones/Marshmallow-Update-for-Lenovo-Vibe-P1/m-p/3317810/highlight/true#M9196). Unfortunately, I don't have the device to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK....I think I have figured out something. This is definitely not a genuine solution, but still it may help..........From settings go to power manager -> background app management and unrestrict all. This helped me & rebooting has stopped but as I have said, this is not a proper solution. Waiting for Lenovo Team to help us asap.

Comment: I click unrestricted .even then phone restarts again

Comment: This worked for me. Than you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

There are quiet a few things  to try in the following order.

1) if it was an official update, and your device is under warranty, then get it repaired.

2) try a factory reset via recovery. Search to find the key combination to get into the recovery and Perform a factory Reset.

3) Android Marshmallow has the ability to grant/restrict specific permissions to apps. Make sure that all system apps and Google apps have all the permissions granted.

4) this step is recommended only if you have some knowledge about the working of an Android device. Connect device to a computer and check the logcat to find what went wrong. try to fix the error that caused the issue.